# JTable does not remove row

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to remove rows form a `JTable`. I wrote the code like this:

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int x = 0;
int row = dtm.getRowCount();

while(row>=x){

    dtm.removeRow(x);
    x++;

}
```

But it generates an error, like:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  24 >= 24
```

Comment: You've got an off-by-one error, because you should be using `>` rather than `>=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler solution is to use:

```
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

This is also more efficient since the table only needs to repaint itself once, after all the rows have been deleted.

Comment: I believe you need to use revalidate() or repaint() with that though

Comment: @Marco No need for that. The model fires the necessary events which are picked up by the `JTable`

Comment: No. The way Swing works is that you update the model and the model notifies the view to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
while(row>x){
    dtm.removeRow(x);
    x++;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(); 
    JTable table = new JTable(model); 

    model.addColumn("Col1"); 
    model.addColumn("Col2"); 
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "2"});
    model.addRow(new Object[]{"1", "2"});

    table.setModel(model);

    for(int index = 0; index<table.getRowCount();)
    {
        model.removeRow(index);
    }
```

With Java installed it is easier. Sorry about the wrong answer.

Comment: -1 same problem: after having removed half of the total rows, accessing the next x will throw because now it greater as the _current_ rowCount